# Update parent and add child in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I get a JSON array of records for POST :-

My Parent table model is as follows :-

```
class UserVehicle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many    :service_bills
end
```

My child table model is as follows :-

```
class ServiceBill < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user_vehicle
end
```

This is my controller code (to update parent and insert child)

```
class Api::V1::ServiceBillsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    service_bill_params[:user_vehicles].each do |user_vehicle|
      @vehicle = UserVehicle.find_by(vehicle_number:  user_vehicle[:vehicle_number])

      if @vehicle
        user_vehicle[:transaction_details].each do |service_bill|
          @service_bill = ServiceBill.create(service_bill)
        end
      else
        p 'vehicle not found'
      end
    end

    begin
      if @service_bill.save
        format_response("Ok", 200, "Transaction details inserted successfully.", service_bill_params)
      end    
    rescue => e
      format_response("Error", 301, e, [])
    end

  end


  private
  def service_bill_params
    service_bill_params = params.require(:service_bill).permit(:user_external_reference, :membership_card_number, user_vehicles: [ :vehicle_number,  :mobile_number, :total_savings, :current_mileage_reading, :last_service_visit, :current_tier, :next_mileage_tier, transaction_details: [:transaction_id, :transaction_external_reference, :total_savings, :amount_paid, :total_bill_amount, :transaction_date] ])
  end
end
```

The above code does nothing, the terminal says BEGIN and a ROLLBACK immediately. I'm assuming I've missed something with the parent child relationship design?

Comment: Add up some code here which performs this task

Comment: Hi - in Stack Overflow we expect you to have a go at writing your code before coming to ask us for help. If you have done this, then you should put that code in your question (even if it isn't working) so that we can see that you've put in the effort, and we can then help you debug the broken code. If you haven't, give it a whirl - see how far you can get. Try and do the parts that you know how to do first, and leave a space for the parts you don't... get those bits working and then try the bits you're not sure of. Then come back to us to help you with those.

Comment: Sorry. I will add the code and exact scenario shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use rails nested attributes, pass the parent & child in a hash & then save them using a single method(save). You can read the rails documentation(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Api::V1::ServiceBillsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    service_bill_params[:user_vehicles].each do |user_vehicle|
      @vehicle = UserVehicle.find_by(vehicle_number:  user_vehicle[:vehicle_number])

      if @vehicle

        user_vehicle[:transaction_details].each do |service_bill|

          service_bill[:current_mileage_reading] = user_vehicle[:remaining_mileage_for_next_tier]
          service_bill[:dealer_identification] = 1234
          @vehicle.update(user_vehicle.except(:transaction_details))
          @vehicle.service_bills.create(service_bill)


        end
      else
        p 'vehicle not found'
      end
    end

    begin
      if @vehicle.save
        format_response("Ok", 200, "Transaction details saved successfully.", service_bill_params)

      end    
    rescue => e
      format_response("Error", 301, e, [])
    end



  end



  def format_response(status, code, message, data)
    render json: {
      status: status,
      status_code: code,
      status_message: message,
      data: data
    }
  end

  private
  def service_bill_params
    service_bill_params = params.require(:service_bill).permit(:user_external_reference, :membership_card_number, user_vehicles: [ :vehicle_number, :total_savings, :last_transaction_date, :current_tier, :remaining_mileage_for_next_tier, transaction_details: [:transaction_id, :transaction_external_reference, :total_savings, :amount_paid, :total_bill_amount, :transaction_date] ])
  end
end
```

This seems to have worked. Thank you.